# Installing and running Web Management Console in Apache Felix OSGI

Tags: apache-felix

I 'm trying to install and run Apache Felix Web Management Console ( 4.2.0 ) in Apache Felix 4.2.1 but it does not work.

I have installed Felix Http Jetty 2.2.1 bundle, Felic Configuration Admin Service 1.8.0 bundle, Log Service 1.0.1 bundle, EventAdmin 1.3.2 bundle and Felix Web Management Console 4.2.0

When I try to start the Web Management Console it says :

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.apache.felix.webconsole_4.2.0 [29]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.apache.commons.fileupload; version="[1.2.0,2.0.0)"

I'm using Java 1.6.0.26, Ubuntu 12.10!

```
jonathan@JONATHAN:/datos/jonathan/Programas/apache-felix-framework-4.2.1$ java -jar bin/felix.jar 

2013-10-22 16:38:37.389:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
2013-10-22 16:38:37.412:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}

____________________________
Welcome to Apache Felix Gogo

g! 2013-10-22 16:38:37.434:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8888

lb

START LEVEL 1
ID|State      |Level|Name
0|Active     |    0|OSGi System Bundle (3.7.2.v20120110-1415)
1|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Bundle Repository (1.6.6)
2|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.12.0)
3|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.10.0)
4|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.10.0)
23|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Configuration Admin Service (1.8.0)
24|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Log Service (1.0.1)
26|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Http Jetty (2.2.1)
27|Active     |    1|Apache Felix EventAdmin (1.3.2)
29|Installed  |    1|Apache Felix Web Management Console (4.2.0)
g! start 29

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.apache.felix.webconsole_4.2.0 [29]" >could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package:     org.apache.commons.fileupload; version="[1.2.0,2.0.0)"

g!
```

Regards

Comment: By the way, I'm NOT using Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issues, I resolved them by clearing up the Felix installation, then I started the Felix from scratch, this means, I had something like this on the Apache Felix Gogo:

```
____________________________
Welcome to Apache Felix Gogo

g! lb
START LEVEL 1
   ID|State      |Level|Name
    0|Active     |    0|System Bundle (4.6.0)
    1|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Bundle Repository (2.0.2)
    2|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.14.0)
    3|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.12.1)
    4|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.10.0)
g!
```

So, on the console, just add the following command

```
list -v
```

It will give you the list of available packages, so, just look for the Webconsole package name and run this (always on the Gogo console):

```
g! deploy org.apache.felix.webconsole
```

This will download the required libraries, and print the following on the Console:

```
Target resource(s):
-------------------
   Apache Felix Web Management Console (3.1.2)

Required resource(s):
---------------------
   Apache Felix Configuration Admin Service (1.2.4)
   Apache Felix Http Bundle (2.0.4)
   Apache Felix Log Service (1.0.0)
   Apache Felix HTTP Service Jetty (1.0.0)

Optional resource(s):
---------------------
   OSGi R4 Compendium Bundle (4.0.0)
   Apache Felix Declarative Services (1.6.0)
   Apache Felix iPOJO (1.8.0)
   Apache Felix iPOJO WebConsole Plugins (1.6.0)
   Apache Felix Shell Service (1.4.2)

Deploying...
done.
g!
```

So, now, if you run lb (list bundles command)

```
g! lb
START LEVEL 1
   ID|State      |Level|Name
    0|Active     |    0|System Bundle (4.6.0)
    1|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Bundle Repository (2.0.2)
    2|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.14.0)
    3|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.12.1)
    4|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.10.0)
    5|Installed  |    1|Apache Felix Configuration Admin Service (1.2.4)
    6|Installed  |    1|Apache Felix Http Bundle (2.0.4)
    7|Installed  |    1|Apache Felix Log Service (1.0.0)
    8|Installed  |    1|OSGi R4 Compendium Bundle (4.0.0)
    9|Installed  |    1|Apache Felix Declarative Services (1.6.0)
   10|Installed  |    1|HTTP Service (1.0.0)
   11|Installed  |    1|Apache Felix iPOJO (1.8.0)
   12|Installed  |    1|Apache Felix Web Management Console (3.1.2)
   13|Installed  |    1|Apache Felix iPOJO WebConsole Plugins (1.6.0)
   14|Installed  |    1|Apache Felix Shell Service (1.4.2)
g!
```

So, now, just look for the bundles "HTTP Service" and "Apache Felix Web Management Console" and start them:

```
g! start 10
g! start 12
```

And finally, just go the the path (default port is 8080):

```
http://localhost:28372/system/console/bundles
```

By the way, you can change the port on the config.properties (in Felix) by just adding the following parameter:

```
org.osgi.service.http.port=28372
```

Hope this may help somebody else...

Comment: @JohnSaunders: one of your edits was rolled back here. I'm not sure I can flag because of [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320874) relating to another user - perhaps you might consider handling/flagging it? Thanks.

Comment: No matter @John, Marco has kindly given way on this matter, on another post.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I get it.

In a blank Felix installation:

```
g! bundlelevel -i 1
g! mvnrepo = http://repo2.maven.org/maven2
g! start $mvnrepo/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.jar
g! start $mvnrepo/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.2.1/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
g! start http://maven.ow2.org/maven2/org/json/org.ow2.chameleon.commons.json/20090911-0002/org.ow2.chameleon.commons.json-20090911-0002.jar
g! bundlelevel -i 5
g! start $mvnrepo/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.webconsole/4.2.0/org.apache.felix.webconsole-4.2.0.jar
```